# How do I calculate the reminder (mod)

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I want to calculate the reminder for high power value using casio (fx-991es) 
Ex:
$$
87^{17} \ \bmod 77
$$

This method not working because the number is too large 
Ex: 
$$
9/2=4.5=
4-4.5=0.5=
0.5*2=1
$$

Comment: You can repeatedly square 87 and take Mod 77 after each squaring. After squaring 4 times, you'll have raised 87 to the power $2^4 = 16$, so you then need to multiply the result by 87 to obtain $87^{17}$.

Comment: ... and $87\equiv 10$ to begin with

Comment: Also, what is the significance of that $9/2=\ldots$ line?

Comment: Thank you. But I knew this method, Im seeking for direct method

Comment: @Mahmood The direct method is just taking $87^{17}$. Successive squaring is how you do it when that's not possible

Answer (score 1):

You could go about like this:

$$
87^{17}\equiv_{77} 10^{17}=10\cdot(10^2)^8=10\cdot100^8\equiv_{77}=10\cdot23^8
$$
then since $23^2=529\equiv_{77}67$ we have
$$
10\cdot(23^2)^4\equiv10\cdot67^4
$$
and you keep on like this always reducing the base by breaking up the exponent.

Hope this helps

Comment: $100\equiv 23\not\equiv 33$

Comment: ohh thats true...thanks (it's early in the morning)

Answer (score 0):

$87^{17} \equiv 10^{17} \pmod{77}$

$10^2 \equiv 23 \pmod{77}$

$10^4 \equiv (10^2)^2 \equiv 23^2 \equiv 67 \pmod{77}$

$10^8 \equiv 67^2 \equiv 23 \pmod{77}$

$10^{16} \equiv 23^2 \equiv 67 \pmod{77}$

$10^{17} \equiv 10^{16} \cdot 10 \equiv 67 \cdot 10 \equiv 54 \pmod{77}$